# Getting F# on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, f#

I followed [this](http://strangelights.com/fsharp/wiki/WikiEdit.aspx?topic=FSharpWiki.MonoLinux) to get F# on my Ubuntu machine. However, it returned me an error, saying

> -- Resigning FSharp.Core.dll with mono.snk
>   ./install-mono.sh: 24: sn: not found
>   -- Installing FSharp DLLS into the GAC
>   Failure adding assembly bin/FSharp.Core.dll to the cache: Strong name cannot be verified for delay-signed assembly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sn` utility is in the package mono-devel. So `sudo apt-get install mono-devel` and try again.

By the way: if you type `sn` into bash it will tell you which package you need to install to get sn. So the next time, you get a "command not found" error just try to type the command name into bash.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the reason for this issue is that FSharp.Core.dll needs to be re-signed with the Mono key at github.com/mono/mono/raw/master/mcs/class/mono.snk as described at bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=615445 The solution to this issue is to re-sign the F# dll (download mono.snk, then run "sn -q -R FSharp.Core.dll mono.snk") as described by sepp2k.

However, since pre-built F# .deb packages for Ubuntu are now available at http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/ which work out-of-the-box without any need for dll re-signing you can simply use those instead.

Comment: Perfect! Solved my problem installing the .NET 4 Visualization assembly to the Mono GAC.